# Execution time of PostgreSQL `copyIn()` is prolonged, and it results in an error

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, hikaricp

I wanted to insert millions of records into one of my table, I read in the Postgresql documentation, that `COPY` command is the fastest way to achieve this.

Also, I'm using Hikari connection pooling.

Table name - `evnt_slt`
schema name - `public`

Columns:

```
id uuid,
evt_id uuid,
loc_type character varying,
loc_id character varying",
date character varying,
strt_tym character varying",
end_tym character varying,
zone bpchar,
registrationcount integer DEFAULT 0,
created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
createdby character varying,
lastmodified timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
lastmodifiedby character varying,
slt_preference jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb
```

Payload: (For simplicity, I kept a single data. And, I'm processing this payload and storing it to the `SlotData` Object)

```
[
    {
        "date": "2024-03-03",
        "maxRegistration": 10,
        "locationId": "0003",
        "restriction": "perEvent",
        "locationType": "STORE",
        "startTime": "06:00",
        "endTime": "21:00"
    },
    and so on
]

public class SlotData {
  private UUID id;
  private String eventId;
  private String locationType;
  private String locationId;
  private String date;
  private String startTime;
  private String endTime;
  private String timezone;
  private int currentRegistration;
  private OffsetDateTime created;
  private String createdBy;
  private OffsetDateTime lastModified;
  private String lastModifiedBy;
  private JSONObject preference;
}
```

I tried the below code.

```
List<SlotData> slotDatas = new ArrayList<>(); 

String copyQuery = "COPY public.evnt_slt (id, evt_id, loc_type, loc_id, date, strt_tym, end_tym, zone, registrationcount, created, createdby, lastmodified, lastmodifiedby, preference) FROM STDIN CSV"

        DataSource datasource = writeNamedJdbcTemplate.getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource();
        
        if(datasource != null) {
            Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
            Connection rawConnection = connection.unwrap(Connection.class);
            
            if(rawConnection.isWrapperFor(PGConnection.class)) {
                
                PGConnection pgConnection = rawConnection.unwrap(PGConnection.class);
                CopyManager copyManager = pgConnection.getCopyAPI();
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                StringBuilder copyCommand = new StringBuilder();
                copyCommand.append(copyQuery);
                
                StringBuilder copyData = new StringBuilder();
                
                for(SlotData slotData : slotDatas) {
                    copyData.append(slotData.getId().toString());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getEventId().toString());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(escapeAndQuote(slotData.getLocationType()));
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getLocationId().toString());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getDate().toString());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getStartTime().toString());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getEndTime().toString());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getTimezone());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getCurrentRegistration());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getCreated().toString());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getCreatedBy().toString());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getLastModified().toString());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getLastModifiedBy());
                    copyData.append(",");
                    copyData.append(slotData.getPreference().toString());
                    copyData.append("\n");
                    
                }
                
                
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(copyData.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                copyManager.copyIn(copyCommand.toString(), is);
                connection.commit();
                
                connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            }else {
                System.out.println("Not a PGConnection");
            }
            
            connection.close();
        }
    While executing the copyManager.copyIn(copyCommand.toString(), is) , the internal implementation of the copyIn() throws this error <br>
```

**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: Remote host terminated the handshake**

I would be grateful for any assistance in addressing this issue. Thanks!

Comment: The error is *SSL error: Remote host terminated the handshake*, so I would say this has to do with improper SSL setup.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 

In their source code, it says
"There is a bug in the server's implementation of the copy protocol. It returns the command complete immediately upon receiving the EOF marker in the binary protocol potentially before we've issued CopyDone. When we are not blocking, we don't think we are done, so we hold off on processing command complete and any subsequent messages
       until we actually are done with the copy."

https://github.com/buggins/postgresql-native/blob/master/java-source/org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl.java

Comment: Where is `buggins` entering this? Why not use the Postgres jDBC driver [CopyManager](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/server-prepare/#copymanager)? Also to me it looks like the COPY  never gets started as the SSL handshake fails.

Comment: I'm still using the jdbc CopyManager. U can see in the posted code

Comment: 1) The link you provides is to a different project, albeit one that seems to use the Postgres JDBC code. 2) You need to research the SSL issue. Suggestions: a) Look at the Postgres log to see what is happening? My guess is won't see anything as it never gets that far.  b) Try a connection to the Postgres instance using `psql` and then just a JDBC connection without COPY.